# How do I export a postgresql database schema to an XML format?

Tags: sql, xml, database, postgresql, database-schema

Uh... How do I export a postgresql database schema to an XML format?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use one of the functions `table_to_xml`, `schema_to_xml`, etc.  See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING).

Answer (score 2):

I use [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org) for this purpose.

I think [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com) can it as well.